# Findbugs for Android project with libraries in ant build

Tags: android, ant, findbugs

[Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is a great software and my team uses it while working on our Android project. In Eclipse everything is nice and shiny, however now we're trying to automate our builds with `ant` and generate Findbugs results automatically for each build.

It's seems not that difficult. I followed this tutorial:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project#BuildinganAndroidappandtestproject-FindBugs
One minor issue is that I had to change `${android.jar}` to `${project.target.android.jar}`.

The worse part are `The following classes needed for analysis were missing:` warnings for classes that come form library projects we use. Some of them are our own and we would like to scan them with Findbugs, too. To make matters more complicated, one of these libs uses another lib (also our own and needs scanning), so it looks like this:
`Project A --uses--> Library B --uses--> Library C`

Here I thought that since Android SDK can handle all these dependencies (Library C is compiled when I issue `ant debug` for Project A), I can somehow make use of it, get the list of libs my project depends on and provide it to the findbugs task. Unfortunately I haven't managed to do that.

For now I settled with manually entering all libs, some into `class` property of findbugs task, some into `auxClasspath`, which has the upside that I can only analyse some of the libraries the project depends on. Still I hope that what I originally tried to do is possible. Can anybody show me how to extract a path-element

Comment: I managed to find that `dependency` task sets `project.library.folder.path` path-like variable, however it holds paths to the root folder of each library, no to the `bin/classes` folder. And unfortunately I don't know ant well enough to know what to do with that.

Answer (score 3):

I've finally found that part of SDK build script that puts together a "classpath" of all the jars (`classes.jar`-s of all the libraries, including Library C from the "diagram" and jars from the `libs/` folder of the project and all the libs).

My final `custom-rules.xml` with findbugs target looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Project_custom" default="findbugs">

    <taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"/>

    <target name="findbugs">
        <gettarget
                androidJarFileOut="project.target.android.jar"
                androidAidlFileOut="project.target.framework.aidl"
                bootClassPathOut="project.target.class.path"
                targetApiOut="project.target.apilevel"
                minSdkVersionOut="project.minSdkVersion" />
        <dependency
                libraryFolderPathOut="project.library.folder.path"
                libraryPackagesOut="project.library.packages"
                libraryManifestFilePathOut="project.library.manifest.file.path"
                libraryResFolderPathOut="project.library.res.folder.path"
                libraryBinAidlFolderPathOut="project.library.bin.aidl.folder.path"
                libraryNativeFolderPathOut="project.library.native.folder.path"
                jarLibraryPathOut="project.all.jars.path"
                targetApi="${project.target.apilevel}"
                verbose="${verbose}" />

        <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}" output="xml" outputFile="findbugs-results.xml">
            <auxClasspath>
                <pathelement location="${project.target.android.jar}" />
                <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
            </auxClasspath>
            <class location="${out.dir}" />

        </findbugs>
    </target>

</project>
```

Edit: I've upgraded the target to run indepent of the build targets, i.e. now you can run just `ant findbugs` not `ant debug findbugs`.

Comment: I got libraryRFilePathOut error when using this configuration

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, but this configuration broke some time after Android SDK update. I fixed it and then it broke again. So unfortunately I don't think this is a good way to do that. Hopefully there will be an easy way to plug in Findbugs in Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I added some extra definition and worked. Thank you

```
<target name="findbugs">
    <mkdir dir="reports" />
    <gettarget
            androidJarFileOut="project.target.android.jar"
            androidAidlFileOut="project.target.framework.aidl"
            bootClassPathOut="project.target.class.path"
            targetApiOut="project.target.apilevel"
            minSdkVersionOut="project.minSdkVersion" />
    <dependency
            libraryFolderPathOut="project.library.folder.path"
            libraryPackagesOut="project.library.packages"
            libraryManifestFilePathOut="project.library.manifest.file.path"
            libraryResFolderPathOut="project.library.res.folder.path"
            libraryBinAidlFolderPathOut="project.library.bin.aidl.folder.path"
            libraryNativeFolderPathOut="project.library.native.folder.path"
            jarLibraryPathOut="project.all.jars.path"
            libraryRFilePathOut="project.library.rfile.path"
            buildToolsFolder="${sdk.dir}/build-tools"
            renderscriptSupportLibsOut="project.rs.support.libs.path"
            renderscriptSupportMode="${renderscript.support.mode}"
            targetApi="${project.target.apilevel}"
            verbose="${verbose}" />
    <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}" output="xml:withMessages" outputFile="reports/findbugs.xml" excludeFilter="findbugs-exclude.xml" maxRank="9">
        <!-- auxClasspath path="${project.target.android.jar}" / -->
        <auxClasspath>
            <pathelement location="${project.target.android.jar}" />
            <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
        </auxClasspath>
        <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src/" />
        <class location="${basedir}/bin/classes/" />
    </findbugs>
</target>
```